# java web app classpath in spring configuration

Tags: java

In java web application, in the root folder, we have WEB-INF, META-INF and some jsp files, what is the classpath refer to in spring configuration? Is it refer to WEB-INF/classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in a webapp `WEB-INF/classes` is on your classpath as all the jars in `WEB-INF/lib` are.

Comment: All the jars in WEB-INF/lib also can be found in classpath?

Comment: Yes, they are all added to the classpath of your running webapp :-)